# Left exactness of the cotangent sequence

Tags: algebraic-geometry, blowup, birational-geometry

I am reading this [note](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0507404.pdf) of Blickle on motivic integration and I am stuck at a technical point. At the beginning of the appendix, we are given a proper birational morphism $f: X' \longrightarrow X$ between smooth $k$-varieties ($k$: a field). In particular, we have a first fundamental sequence
$$f^*\Omega^1_{X/k} \overset{df}{\longrightarrow} \Omega^1_{X'/k} \longrightarrow \Omega^1_{X'/X} \longrightarrow 0.$$
It is claimed that this sequence is also exact on the left by the **birationality** of $f$. It is hard to believe this as birationality just implies that $X$ and $X'$ are isomorphic over some open set but not on the whole spaces.

I tried to google, and in the same situation as the OP of [this topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1510159/cotangent-sequence-for-blow-up), I find no reference for the sequence in the case of blowing up. Assume that it holds true for blowing up, then can we deduce this from the weak factorization theorem (**theorem 3.6**, page 19 in Blickle)?

Answer (score 1):

Both $f^*\Omega_X$ and $\Omega_{X'}$ are locally free sheaves (because $X$ and $X'$ are smooth) and the morphism $df$ is an isomorphism on a dense open subset open (by birationality of $f$). Now the kernel of $df$ is a subsheaf of a locally free sheaf, hence it is torsion free, and it is zero on a dense open subset, hence it is torsion. A combination of these two observations implies it is zero, hence the sequence is left exact.

Comment: Being zero on a dense open set implies being torsion, do you have a reference for this? I found https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2197519/must-a-quasicoherent-sheaf-which-is-zero-on-a-dense-open-subset-be-torsion but I think there is other way around to see this.

Comment: The question is local: if $K = Frac(A)$ and $M \otimes_A K = 0$ then $M$ is torsion. Now $K$ is the colimit of localizations $A_s$ at various nonzero elements $s \in A$, so we may assume $M \otimes_A A_s = 0$. But then every element of $M$ is annihilated by a power of $s$, hence $M$ is torsion.

Comment: The idea is true but it needs to be modified a little. Since $X$ is not integral (we only have smoothness here, and smooth + connected = integral), writing $Frac(A)$ does not make sense. It should be $M \otimes_A A_f = M_f = 0$ from the beginning (here the hypothesis of being dense is used).

Comment: Even in the nonintegral case $Frac(A)$ makes sense --- this is the localization with respect to all nonzero divisors.